# Border radius 50% gradient color

Tags: html, css

I want to create a round border around my div, with a gradient color.
How can I create that?

I want to use this `linear-gradient(142deg, #ED586A, #ED844A);`

I current have this HTML;

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
<p class="inner-text"> TITLE </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-sm-2 p {border: 2px solid #e3e3e3; border-radius: 50%; height: 175px; line-height: 175px; width: 175px;}
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/k8wazLgz/

Comment: Can you apply a solid background on `.col-sm-2 p ` ?

Comment: @Akshay Yes, that is not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the effect by placing an `after` `pseudo-element` below the element with gradient background

> Note:For this to work a solid background color is required otherwise `clip-path` can be used

```css
.col-sm-2 p {
    border: 2px solid #e3e3e3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 175px;
    line-height: 175px;
    width: 175px;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    background:#fff;
}

.col-sm-2 p:after{
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    width:110%;
    height:110%;
    background:linear-gradient(142deg, #ED586A, #ED844A);
    top:-5%;
    left:-5%;
    z-index:-1;
    border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <p class="inner-text">TITLE</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jelle Try it with prefixes maybe that will work like `-webkit-`,`-moz-`

Comment: Nice one @Akshay, just to improve the answer add a note about the need for solid color background on parent (or) indicate the something like `clip-path` would be needed.